# OpenShift MongoError: auth fails how to resolve?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, openshift

**EDIT**  ; attaching my app.js , I am using

```
git add app.js
git commit -m "updated app.js"
git push
```

command to push code from local machine, and my app.js code is as follows :

```
/*
*RESTfull server 
*/
//defining express middleware
var express=require('express');
//require mongoose, this middleware helps in modeling data for mongodb
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
//require passport, this middleware helps in authentiation
var passport=require('passport');
//require passport, this middleware parsing body
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var flash    = require('connect-flash');

//define port on which node app is gonna run
//var port     = process.env.PORT || 8000;
var server_port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080 ;
var server_ip_address = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1' ;

var app=express();


app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());
======================================================================
app.listen(server_port,server_ip_address);
console.log('The magic happens on port ' + 'http://'+server_ip_address+':'+server_port);
```

**EDIT** : 
I commented all mongodb connection code, now my app.js has simple expressjs code, still I can see the same output from the command "rhc tail -a app", Iam not sure why nodejs catridge is trying to connect to mongodb, eventhough there is no code in app.js, is it possible that the log has been generated previously and the same log is being shown ? can I clear log file and test it once? can somebody please help me.

I deployed my nodejs(expressjs) app to the openshift server. I am hitting a mongoError "MongoError: auth fails", I am providing credentials to mongodb server.
Initially when node child process starts it is trying to connect to the
"mongodb://admin:XXXXXX@ip:port" but it should connect to "mongodb://admin:XXXXXX@ip:port/admin" as credentials reside in admin.system.users collection.
I am using mongoose to connect to mongoDB so I changed my mongoose connect to
mongoose.connect(mongodb://admin:XXXXXX@ip:port/admin); But I still see child process is trying to connect to this url "mongodb://admin:XXXXXX@ip:port", but later point of time it connects to the correct collection, and I can see the console ouput of the following code.

```js
  mongoose.connection.once('connected', function() {
    console.log("Connected to database G")
  });
```

I tested few routes, they are working fine. I want to understand why is it behaving so and can I ignore this error or how can I resolve this issue??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL instead of forming your own url.  This environment variable has the following format:

```
mongodb://admin:LX3eZCP6yxxx@123e4b9a5973ca07ca00002f-appname.rhcloud.com:12345/
```

Comment: HI Ben, thanks for the quick reply,I am actually using process environment variables, I just used ip format in question, even then it behaves in the above mentioned manner

Comment: I see... we have several servers on OpenShift and we just use the environment variable without 'admin' at the end of the URL and they all working fine without error.  When mongodb cartridge is created, openshift provided the URL, which is just the environment variable without 'admin' attached.

Comment: Hi Ben, I tried that, still I am facing the same issue. Interestingly this time also same pattern continues and  I get "Connected to database G" message on third attempt, I am pasting my "rhc tail -a app" command output down

Answer (score 0):

Attaching my "rhc tail -a app" commad,

```js
==> app-root/logs/nodejs.log-20150328020443 <==
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node app.js'
mongodb://admin:pass@550f3e705973cab149000009-app.rhcloud.com:59281/

mongodb://admin:pass@550f3e705973cab149000009-app.rhcloud.com:59281/

The magic happens on port http://127.9.17.129:8080
/var/lib/openshift/550f3c0ffcf933066f0001b8/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/m
ongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:246
        throw message;
              ^
MongoError: auth fails
    at Object.toError (/var/lib/openshift/550f3c0ffcf933066f0001b8/app-root/runt
ime/repo/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/utils.js:114:11)

    at /var/lib/openshift/550f3c0ffcf933066f0001b8/app-root/runtime/repo/node_mo
dules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1194:31

==> app-root/logs/nodejs.log-20150327071155 <==
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
DEBUG: Program node app.js exited with code 8
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node app.js'
mongodb://admin:pass@550f3e705973cab149000009-app.rhcloud.com:59281/

mongodb://admin:pass@550f3e705973cab149000009-app.rhcloud.com:59281/

The magic happens on port http://127.9.17.129:8080
/var/lib/openshift/550f3c0ffcf933066f0001b8/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/m
ongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:246
        throw message;
              ^
MongoError: auth fails

==> app-root/logs/nodejs.log <==
DEBUG:   program 'app.js'
DEBUG:   --watch '/var/lib/openshift/550f3c0ffcf933066f0001b8/app-root/data/.nod
ewatch'
DEBUG:   --ignore 'undefined'
DEBUG:   --extensions 'node|js|coffee'
DEBUG:   --exec 'node'
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node app.js'
DEBUG: Watching directory '/var/lib/openshift/550f3c0ffcf933066f0001b8/app-root/
data/.nodewatch' for changes.
admin:pass@550f3e705973cab149000009-app.rhcloud.com:59281
The magic happens on port http://127.9.17.129:8080
Connected to database G

==> app-root/logs/haproxy.log <==
[WARNING] 087/140540 (417258) : Server express/local-gear is UP, reason: Layer7
check passed, code: 200, info: "HTTP status check returned code <3C>200<3E>", ch
eck duration: 1ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers online. 0 sessions requeued, 0
total in queue.
[WARNING] 088/001408 (417258) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer
4 connection problem, info: "Connection refused", check duration: 0ms. 0 active
and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 088/001408 (417258) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
[WARNING] 088/002019 (417258) : Server express/local-gear is UP, reason: Layer7
check passed, code: 200, info: "HTTP status check returned code <3C>200<3E>", ch
eck duration: 29ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers online. 0 sessions requeued, 0
 total in queue.
[WARNING] 088/110018 (417258) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer
4 connection problem, info: "Connection refused", check duration: 0ms. 0 active
and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 088/110018 (417258) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
[WARNING] 088/110112 (417258) : Server express/local-gear is UP, reason: Layer7
check passed, code: 200, info: "HTTP status check returned code <3C>200<3E>", ch
eck duration: 1ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers online. 0 sessions requeued, 0
total in queue.
[WARNING] 088/110502 (417258) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer
4 connection problem, info: "Connection refused", check duration: 0ms. 0 active
and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 088/110502 (417258) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
[WARNING] 088/110556 (417258) : Server express/local-gear is UP, reason: Layer7
check passed, code: 200, info: "HTTP status check returned code <3C>200<3E>", ch
eck duration: 1ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers online. 0 sessions requeued, 0
total in queue.

==> app-root/logs/nodejs.log-20150328074316 <==
The magic happens on port http://127.9.17.129:8080
/var/lib/openshift/550f3c0ffcf933066f0001b8/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/m
ongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:246
        throw message;
              ^
MongoError: auth fails
    at Object.toError (/var/lib/openshift/550f3c0ffcf933066f0001b8/app-root/runt
ime/repo/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/utils.js:114:11)

    at /var/lib/openshift/550f3c0ffcf933066f0001b8/app-root/runtime/repo/node_mo
dules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1194:31
    at /var/lib/openshift/550f3c0ffcf933066f0001b8/app-root/runtime/repo/node_mo
dules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1903:9
    at Server.Base._callHandler (/var/lib/openshift/550f3c0ffcf933066f0001b8/app
-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connec
tion/base.js:453:41)
    at /var/lib/openshift/550f3c0ffcf933066f0001b8/app-root/runtime/repo/node_mo
dules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:487:18

==> app-root/logs/haproxy_ctld.log <==
I, [2015-03-22T18:06:38.808186 #415579]  INFO -- : Starting haproxy_ctld
I, [2015-03-27T14:20:21.556898 #15736]  INFO -- : Starting haproxy_ctld
I, [2015-03-29T12:18:29.365873 #417278]  INFO -- : Starting haproxy_ctld
I, [2015-03-29T12:18:37.485326 #417532]  INFO -- : Starting haproxy_ctld

==> app-root/logs/nodejs.log-20150323084556 <==
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/550f3c0ffcf933066f0001b8/app-root/
runtime/repo/app.js:43:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
DEBUG: Program node app.js exited with code 8

==> app-root/logs/nodejs.log-20150328012640 <==
    at /var/lib/openshift/550f3c0ffcf933066f0001b8/app-root/runtime/repo/node_mo
dules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1194:31
    at /var/lib/openshift/550f3c0ffcf933066f0001b8/app-root/runtime/repo/node_mo
dules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1903:9
    at Server.Base._callHandler (/var/lib/openshift/550f3c0ffcf933066f0001b8/app
-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connec
tion/base.js:453:41)
    at /var/lib/openshift/550f3c0ffcf933066f0001b8/app-root/runtime/repo/node_mo
dules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:487:18
    at MongoReply.parseBody (/var/lib/openshift/550f3c0ffcf933066f0001b8/app-roo
t/runtime/repo/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/responses/
mongo_reply.js:68:5)
    at null.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/550f3c0ffcf933066f0001b8/app-root/ru
ntime/repo/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/ser
ver.js:445:20)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/550f3c0ffcf933066f0001b8/app-root/ru
ntime/repo/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/con
nection_pool.js:207:13)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
DEBUG: Program node app.js exited with code 8
```